# Is it safe to check JDO queries with isEmpty()? Whats the "right" way?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jdo, datanucleus

According to the documentation [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/sql.html) (under "unique results") and [here](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api30/apidocs/index.html), A JDO "default" query result will return a List, and a "unique" specified query returns null if they are empty.

So am I safe to just use `.isEmpty()` to check that I got rows for a normal query? Likewise for those times that a query is marked "unique", should I just use `== null`?

I tested and a empty result does indeed return a List with `.size()` of `0`. So it seems my only danger of a NullPointerException lies with a "unique" query.

What other precautions should I take (if any)? Do I cover my bases acceptably with just those two types of checks? Pretty much looking for some best practice advice, and any potential gotcha's. I am pretty novice with both Java and JDO/ORM persistence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way ? A List is a List and that has a Java contract (API). JDO doesn't change that. Also the JDO spec (and DN docs) define what form of result comes from a query
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/jdoql_result.html

Comment: Yes I realize that the return type is outlined in the docs, I reference it in my question.  I apologize if I was unclear: I believe you are essentially saying, "Yes, that covers your bases." So thank you for the clarification.